# Time Complexity of this nested loops

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o

what is the time complexity of this code? nlgn OR nlgn^2

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i*=2 ) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n ; j*=2 ) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= j ; k++) {
                x++; 
                      }}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: @minigeek thank you, ok

Comment: @mohsensaeb you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for takes log n time  (`exponential growth`)

Second for loop also takes log n time(`exponential growth`)

Third one takes n time(`linear growth`)

So overall time = multiply all ,We get

log n * log n * n

So time complexity is

**O(n (logn)^2)**

Answer (score 0):

the time complexity for this will be n*((logn)^2) because the first loop will run for logn times the second will also run for logn times and the third loop will run for n times as it will be sum of gp 1+2+4+8. So the answer is n*(logn)*(logn)